# remove/stop running job from another thread in apscheduler

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I want to terminate running background job from another thread.
I have the ID for the running job, I am trying to remove using

```
sched.remove_job(job_id)
```

But getting an error:

```
apscheduler.jobstores.base.JobLookupError: 'No job by the id of createjob1536050551951 was found'
```

Is there a way to terminate running job from another thread?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to forcibly end a thread in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I got the way to manage each thread by initializing scheduler globally and add jobs to this scheduler.